# Spring Cloud Stream error handling... error

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

That's not really an issue, beacause I found a workaround, but it conflicts with the documentation, so I wanted to share and document about it.
FYI Spring Boot 2.1.10 + SCSt 2.1.4 + RabbitMQ binder

I first implemented an application local error handler as given into official docs :

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(Person value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!");
}
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT + ".my-group.errors")  // won't work
public void error(ErrorMessage message) {
    log.error("Handling ERROR: " + message.getPayload().getMessage());
}

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=persons.inputs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=my-group
```

But that didn't go well, to say the least. This is what I eventually had to keep:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "persons.inputs.my-group.errors")
```

As you can see, what's happening is that I had to stick to the actual **destination** definition instead of the **channel**'s; which I think is very uncomfortable! And I want to underline, again, that this is contradictory to the official docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_error_handling (plus there are noticeable typos, IMHO: they even write that the destinationName is actually required)

Can anyone share thoughts about the situation with me? Have I done it right and am I right to think that this is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the documentation; it is, indeed, unfortunate the binding name was not used in the error channel name instead of the destination and group, but it's too late to change it now. We could possibly do something in a future release.

Please open 2 [GitHub issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) to

- fix the documentation
- consider adding an option to name the error channel using the binding name instead.